Standard Error and Residual standard error
as I am learning the simple linear regression and I am having some trouble understanding the statistical concepts in the text book Intro to Statistical Learning. Here is the screenshot of the content that I am confused about ScreenShot . As far as I understand, the standard error can be understood as the standard deviation of the means. For example, assume we have a population with unknown mean, we can have five sets of samples from the population and find five different means. Then we can calculate the standard deviation of the five means as the standard error, which tells us how far off the sample mean is from the population mean.
However, in the textbook, there is only one sample mean and the standard error can still be calculated as sigma of the population divided by the square root of n. But how do I know the standard deviation of the population with population mean unknown???
In addition, why is RSE calculated as such formula.To be more specific why use the square root and why divide RSS by n-2???
